# Ubuntu Port Forward Issue

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding

I have a Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, and have port forwarded it on My AT&T Arris Router.

It currently runs openssh-server and a Minecraft Server.

What is bizarre, is that both SSH & Minecraft forwarded ports are on the same device.. SSH works at `***.***.***.7:22` even though the Server IP on ifconfig is `***.***.1.174`. The Minecraft Server just Fails, even though the same device has the `"25565"` port opened to it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for all who have reviewed my question. I have resolved this issue by adding the port using `ufw`.

Comment: Does the minecraft server work from inside the network?

Comment: By the way, while detecting an open ssh port on a public IP is fairly trivial, it is generally best not to publish the information on a public site.  No need to make it easy for anyone, particularly if you are also indicating that you are not experienced with Ubuntu and securing it.

Comment: @Paul True True... quite interesting the issue is. I figured out the issue. Had to use `ufw allow 25565` and reboot ubuntu for it to finally work

Comment: Please add this as the answer and accept